# Security issue in CouchDb

Tags: security, curl, couchdb

I see one strange thing happening to `CouchDb`. When I go `Futon` page I see that I need to login. Otherwise, I will get an error message `Error: anathorized` if I try to change some `view` function. And when I login, this error goes away. So, this seems ok.

What is not ok is that when I try to invoke some `view` with `curl` without providing `user` and `password`, I do not get any error message, but get some result. I do it like this:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/db/_design/query/_view/delete/?key="object_1_"'
```

This `view` ^^^ is supposed to return a long list of data. In fact, 26 rows. And this is what I see in Futon when I'm logged in. But here as a result of `curl` command I get:

```
{"total_rows":26,"offset":25,"rows":[{"id":"...","key":"object_1_","value":"..."}]}
```

So, as you can see I get one row of data. I have several questions. Why does `CouchDb` enable to query itself without providing `user` and `password`, when they are required? And why does it return so strange result - total_rows = 26, but in fact there is only one single row.

PS. Ubuntu 15.04, CouchDb 1.6.0

**EDIT**

If I provide user and password like this:

```
 curl 'http://user:password@....similar'
```

then I still get this strange result with one row of data.

Comment: Have you checked your _security document? Maybe post it here so we can see. http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/database/security.html

Comment: Hm. I've checked it and it is `{}`. How can it be `{}`, if there is at least one user?

Comment: BTW. Even if we suppose, that for some reason some process did something wrong with some configuration files and as a result it is now possible to query the database, why still my view returns only one single row and why it is different from what I see in Futon (26 rows). Is there any secret option I should provide with curl command, or are there some strongly required options, that I miss and cause this trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not restrict the database to any admins, admin_roles, users or user_roles - so ANYBODY has access to that database. This is DEFAULT and stated in the documentationen.

Why your view does return "strange results" does depend on your view and query.

Comment: If I did not restrict, why then in Futon I can not edit any views, unless I log in? And still what is wrong with the curl command, don't you know? Why when I'm logged in and run a view in Futon I get compeletely different resukt from what I get, when I do it with curl (with user and password provided like `http://user:password@....`

Comment: "does return "strange results" does depend on your view and query". The catch it is the very same view, that I run in Futon and through curl.

Comment: I just can not understand any logic behind `{"total_rows":26, ..., "rows":[{...one single row...}]}` So, why not `"total_rows":1` ?

Comment: The result you get is totally valid. Your query for `?key="object_1_"` CAN only give a single document which you do get. The `"total_rows":26` does state that the view contains a total amount of 26 documents, that number has nothing to do with your query, its intended to be used for pagination. The `"offset":25` says the document you got is at position 26 in that view, what makes it the last document.

Comment: Thanks! Now I get it. However, this `total_rows` which has nothing to do with the query (what I find counter-intuitive) drives me a bit crazy. I can not imagine any situation where I would use this number for pagination. Lets say I had a page size 5 and the view returned 10 rows, but showed not this number 10, but number 26 - how would I use it?

Comment: There is a good guide for couchdb and pagination: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/recipes.html#pagination

Comment: Thanks! That is useful.